# Проверка существование Таблицы sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Помогите решить задачу которая связана с проверка sqlite3 на наличие таблицы. Допустим мне надо чтобы если таблица уже создана то выводилась не подобная ошибка
table b already exists
Я конечно пытался искать по форумам обход подобной ошибки был подобный вариант  OperationalError но он не подходит

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('bd/to.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE kon'+o+' (id int auto_increment primary key,vopros char(150),otv1 varchar(50),otv2 varchar(50),otv3 varchar(50),pravotv varchar(50))')
try:
    print('ok')
except OperationalError:
    print('есть')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно проверить следующим способом:

`SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='название_таблицы';`

или же так:

`create table if not exists название_таблицы;`